# Multi Nested JSON in hive

Tags: json, hive, nested

I have the following input with nested JSON, I want to ingest this data into hive in multiple rows

`"taxes": [{
        "line_id": 1,
        "commodity_code": "997159",
        "fee": {
            "amt": {
                "curr_code": "USD",
                "value": "71.4"
            },
            "type": "receiver"
        },
        "ship_addr": {
            "admin_area_1": "MAHARASHTRA",
            "country_code": "IN"
        },
        "total_tax": {
            "curr_code": "USD",
            "value": "12.8520000000"
        },
        "tax-details": [{
            "exempt_option": false,
            "auth_name": "India Maharashtra Central GST",
            "doc_amt": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "6.43"
            },
            "unrnd_doc_amt": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "6.4260000000"
            },
            "rate": "0.09",
            "rate_code": "SR",
            "non_basis_doc_amt": "0.00",
            "exempt_doc_amt": "0.00",
            "jdx_memo": "INSS2: Tax payable in Seller location.",
            "seller_reg_no": "27AAGCP4442G1ZF",
            "admin_zone_level": "Country",
            "auth_type": "CGST",
            "erp_code": "MHCGST",
            "inv_desc": "Standard Rate - CGST",
            "basis_doc_amt": "71.40"
        }, {
            "exempt_option": false,
            "auth_name": "India Maharashtra State GST",
            "doc_amt": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "6.43"
            },
            "unrnd_doc_amt": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "6.4260000000"
            },
            "rate": "0.09",
            "rate_code": "SR",
            "non_basis_doc_amt": "0.00",
            "exempt_doc_amt": "0.00",
            "jdx_memo": "INSS2: Tax payable in Seller location.",
            "seller_reg_no": "27AAGCP4442G1ZF",
            "admin_zone_level": "Province",
            "auth_type": "SGST",
            "erp_code": "MHSGST",
            "inv_desc": "Standard Rate - SGST",
            "basis_doc_amt": "71.40"
        }],
        "transaction_type": "DS"
    }]`

---

I am using the following DDL

```
select 

    get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].line_id')) as line_id
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].commodity_code')) as commodity_code
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].fee.amt.curr_code')) as curr_code
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].fee.amt.value')) as value
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].fee.type')) as type
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].ship_addr.admin_area_1')) as admin_area
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].ship_addr.country_code')) as country_code
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].total_tax.curr_code')) as total_tax_curr_code
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes[',e.i,'].total_tax.value')) as total_tax_value
    get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].exempt_option')) as exempt_option
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].auth_name')) as auth_name
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].doc_amt.currency_code')) as doc_amt_currency_code
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].doc_amt.value')) as doc_amt_value
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].unrnd_doc_amt.currency_code')) as unrnd_doc_amt_currency_code
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].unrnd_doc_amt.value')) as unrnd_doc_amt_value
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].rate')) as rate
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].rate_code')) as rate_code
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].non_basis_doc_amt')) as non_basis_doc_amt
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].exempt_doc_amt')) as exempt_doc_amount
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].jdx_memo')) as jdx_memo
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].seller_reg_no')) as seller_reg_no
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].admin_zone_level')) as admin_zone_level
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].auth_type')) as auth_type
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].erp_code')) as erp_code
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].inv_desc')) as inv_desc
  , get_json_object(t.json,concat('$.taxes.tax_details[',f.g,'].basis_doc_amt')) as basis_doc_amt



FROM json_2002 t
    LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE (split(get_json_object(json,'$.taxes[*].line_id'),'","')) e as i,x
    LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE (split(get_json_object(json,'$taxes.tax_details[*].exempt_option'),'","')) f as g,h
```

Comment: I used the below DDL but  its not working as expected , please let me know where I am doing it wrong

Comment: I cannot use JSON Serde since few other fields in my file are not in JSON format..I can use either get_json_object/json_tuple/explode/posexplode

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by using regex_replace

LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE (split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(json,'$.taxes.tax_details[*].exempt_option'), '\[|\]', ''), ',' ) ) f as g,h

solved my problem